# Django: DetailView get objects from foreignkey

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset, django-class-based-views

I have a class-based DetailView for my model Event and want to show kategorie entries that are related by foreignkey.

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('events:event-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Kategorie(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('events:kategorie-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**views.py**

```
class EventDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Event
    context_object_name = 'event'
```

**event_detail.html** 
*How can I get the kategories that are related to the event? Until now I used functional views.*

`<ul>
  {% for kategorie in kategorien %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'events:kategorie-detail' kategorie.id %}">{{kategorie}}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>`

Answer (score 2):

Your `event_detail.html` should have this:

```
<ul>
    {% for kategorie in event.kategorie_set.all %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'events:kategorie-detail' kategorie.id %}">{{ kategorie }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The view you use has nothing to do with it. You just iterate through `event.kategorie_set.all`.