# Display a ForeignKey model objects and in detailView and filter it in template based on the post.id

Tags: django-views, django-templates

I’ve two models which display in the same panel in admin using `TabularInline`

**models.py**

```
class Multimg(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=50, null="true", blank=True)
    text = tinymce_models.HTMLField(null="true")
    multimg = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", verbose_name='Image', null="true", blank=True,)
   
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    highlight = models.TextField(max_length=250, null="true", blank=True,)
    image_article = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", verbose_name='Image', null="true")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**admin.py**

```
class MultiAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Multimg
    extra = 3

@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Post
    inlines = [ MultiAdmin ]
```

I want to display the objects of these two models in the same details template and filter their objects to display based on the `Post.id`
I’m using `get_context_data` to display the element of the Multimg Model

the Post model is causing no problems
But when I try to display the Multimg object I cannot display the objects related only to the post details

**views.py**

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
        context['multimgs'] = Multimg.objects.all()
        return context
```

**post_detail.html**

```
      <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>

      <p> {{ post.author }}</p>
      <p> {{ post.date_posted|date:"M d, Y" }} </p>

      {% if post.image_article %}
      <img src="{{ post.image_article.url }}">
      {% endif %}

      {% for multimg in posts %}
      <p> {{ multimg.caption }}</p>
      <p> {{multimg.text|safe }}</p>

      {% if multimg.multimg %}
      <img src="{{ multimg.multimg.url }}">
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

I’m able to display all its object using the tag `{% for multimg in multimgs %}` but when I try to display only the objects related to that particular post detail using `{% for multimg in posts %}` I display nothing.

I’m assuming the context is not able to make a relationship between that particular detail post and the object of this model but I’m confused about the approach I should use in order to achieve that.
Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053636/django-detailview-get-objects-from-foreignkey?rq=1)

Using          `{% for multimg in object.multimg_set.all %}`

Solved the problem